# jQuery Sliders won't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-slider

I don't know why the sliders won't show up or the random color swatch. i've been messing with it for about an hour and have tried everything i know how to do. This is my first time using jQuery and javascript for a project. The end result will be a plugin-game where you try and guess the hex color code of the randomly generated swatch using the sliders.  Here is all my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/RDtCe/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jQuery, neither the $.fn.hexed function, nor the genSwatch function is called. In this fiddle, I've called both of them for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/RDtCe/11

```
genSwatch();
```

and

```
$.fn.hexed();
```

Comment: thanks, whats the reason that the genSwatch function isnt working though

Answer (score 0):

Your hexed function is never called.